# visitNumber getting reset in BigQuery Export of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We've used the following query to inspect visitNumber over time and found that for a particular fullVisitorId they can have more than one 'first' visit.

```
select
  count(distinct fullVisitorId) as users,
  newVisits
From(
  select fullVisitorId, visitNumber, count(distinct visitId) as newVisits
  from table_date_range([91311726.ga_sessions_], timestamp('20151101'), timestamp('20161124') )
  where visitNumber = 1
  group by fullVisitorId, visitNumber )
group by newVisits;
```

Result:

```
| users     | newVisits  |
|-----------|------------|
| 18        | 3          |
| 26041561  | 1          |
| 237792    | 2          |
```

My understanding is that for Universal Analytics the visitNumber is a counter on the Google Analytics backend that iterates for each new session per fullVisitorId, so how is it possible to have more than one session with vistNumber = 1?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 main causes for this.

1. Visits spanning multiple day boundaries. Say a visit starts at 20151101 @11:45pm and lasts until 20151102 @ 1:00am This can create 2 different sessions but the visitNumber won't be incremented.
2. If a user last session was over 183 days ago it will be considered a new user and it's visitNumber will reset to 1. The reason is because Analytics has to do a lookback to see when was the last session to increase the visitNumber count, but the maximum lookback is 183 days. So maybe a user visited on 20151101 and then only came back on 20160701, this would cause both visits to have a visitNumber=1

Comment: Is the maximum lookback also applied in the google analytics new user definition?

Comment: Linking to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187173/is-google-analytics-new-user-affected-by-lookback-window) from @Ichta that is related and helpful in the topic of this question.